# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (socket.io + nodejs)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to a socket.io server, and see if i can initiate connections, basically benchmarking. Here's the code snippet.

```
function initiate() {

    var client = io.connect('http://<ip>:<port>', { 'force new connection' : true});
    client.on('connect', function () {
     client.emit('topic', ('Connection '));
     client.emit('start-typing', 'started typing');
     client.emit('topic-message', 'Topic message');
     // initiate();
    });

  client.on('connect_error', function (err) {
   console.log('connect error');
  });

  client.on('error', function (err) {
   client.emit('error', err);
  });



setTimeout(function () {
 // process.nextTick(initiate);
 initiate();
 });
}

initiate();
```

Now the problem is, after around 3000 connections, it just breaks with call stack size exceeded error. I tried process.nextTick(), also i did put the the socket code inside setTimeout, but it didn't help. I'm trying to hit, at least 1 million connections.

Comment: setTimeout clears the callstack on each recurse, so that's not the cause. This error usually occurs when a function recursively gets called without the callstack being cleared. I don't see a cause in your code.

Comment: Do you realize that you're in an infinite loop calling `initiate()` over and over again opening a new socket.io connection in every time through the loop and never closing the previous one.  You will exhaust various system resources after a short while.

Comment: To hit a million connections from a single computer, you would likely need a very, very specific configuration of computer/OS/node.js.

Comment: Lots of good articles here: https://www.google.com/search?q=max+connections+in+node.js&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&oq=max+connections+in+node.js

Comment: @jfriend00 If i close the client connection, it will actually lose the purpose of benchmarking i suppose ? I don't want the connection to get closed, i would like it to remain open. Please correct me if i'm wrong.  In that case i should set my system resources high ?

Comment: If I were doing this, I wouldn't use recursion.  I'd set up a `for` loop where I could control the number of times `initiate()` was called and then you have to follow all the tuning guides to enable a large number of connections and then when you start running into problems you have to study what type of resource you're running out of at the end and figure out how to get more of that (memory, sockets, etc...).